# What are the behind the scenes MySQL Workbench Standard TCP/IP over SSH commands?

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I am able to connect to our MySQL database using Standard TCP/IP over SSH within MySQL Workbench.  My question is what are the command line commands that make this possible?  I'm trying to write a PHP program that can connect to a remote database through an SSH tunnel but all of the websites I've searched and read assume that the server I'm tunneling to is also the database server. (like this one: http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html).  This is different from my setup.  My setup is basically client > server > database_server.  If I could find out what the commands are being used in MySQL Workbench, I might be able to figure out how to code my app.

I have included a snapshot of the MySQL Workbench settings dialog that I've been successful working with:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're connecting to an Amazon RDS instance. Why not just open up the port to your current location and connect directly?

Comment: I don't have access at this point, and I believe that those who do may not know how to do this.  Do you have directions that I can share with them that may help me explain what needs to happen?

Comment: This is probably the best place to start. I know I can use Workbench from work to hit our main DB. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a page that described perfectly what I needed to do:
https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21009887-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel

So basically the syntax for me was:
ssh -L 3389:myserver-production.wervyvvr9asdf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@256.256.256.256 -i ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.pem

The connect string was:
mysql -u myusername -P 3389 -h 127.0.0.1 mydbname -p

I used port 3389 because its the windows remote desktop port which I'll never use and it was already open, so no need to bug our network admins to mess with firewall settings.  Also where  the IP is 256.256.256.256, you'll want to substitute a valid IP here.